# Tensorflow - How to get the gradients of the output w.r.t the model parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I would like to know if it is possible to compute the gradients of the output of a model with respect to the model parameters.  In other words I would like to compute `dy / d theta`.

Here is a short example of what I mean:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

# Dummy input
test = np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 1)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 1))

model = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, padding = 'same', activation='elu') (x)
model = keras.layers.Flatten() (model)
model = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu') (model)
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(1) (model)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    y = sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={x: test})

    # Get gradients of y w.r.t model parameters.
    gradients = sess.run(tf.gradients(y, model_parameters))
```

I have looked at the documentation of `tf.gradients()` and it states

> `ys` and `xs` are each a `Tensor` or a list of tensors. `grad_ys` is a list of `Tensor`, holding the gradients received by the `ys`. The list must be the same length as `ys`.

So I do understand that both args need to be a tensor. However, when I try

`model_parameters = tf.trainable_variables()`

`model_parameters` is a list of elements of type `tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable`

Is there a way to get the parameters of the model as a tensor to use for differentiation?

Comment: What do you mean by "parameters of the model" in this case?

Comment: I mean the weights of the model.  In math  it would be `d y/ d theta`

Comment: Well those *are* the variables. Or what else do you think the variables is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out.  If I want to compute the gradients of the output with respect to the variables of the network it goes like this.

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

# Dummy input
test = np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 1)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 1))

model = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, padding = 'same', activation='elu') (x)
model = keras.layers.Flatten() (model)
model = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu') (model)
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(1) (model)

# This was the part that I was missing.
============================================================
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
gradient_step = opt.compute_gradients(predictions, tf.trainable_variables())
============================================================

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)

    # This part changed too.
    ==========================================================
    gradients = sess.run(gradient_step, feed_dict={x: test})
    ==========================================================
```

I had to define an optimizer `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` and then feed the `predictions` to the `gradient_step` operation to find the gradient for my output. It was actually pretty simple!

Thank you all for your help ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Two things here.

1. Theta corresponds to the weights in the layers.
2. To get weights in Keras, use `get_weights()`. Do something like following:

   ```
   m1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 5, padding = 'same', activation='elu')  
   model = m1 (x)  
   W1 = m1.get_weights()
   ```

Now you can see W1 constains the weights.